# Converting a random item of a list to uppercase

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random

I'm trying to convert a random item (line) and save it back into the list so that when I print the whole list it prints the full list but with a random line in uppercase.

Here is what I tried, but it does not work:

```
import random
lines = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
random.choice(lines).upper()
print(lines)
```

Example of desired output:

```
abc
def
GHI
jki
```

Comment: it does you just don't see it because you don't grab the value returned from `upper()`;  use `print(random.choice(lines).upper())`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to convert the line and have it save back into the list so that when I print the whole list it prints a random line in uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, it picks a random index and then converts the corresponding element in the list to uppercase.

```
import random
lines = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
choice_idx = random.randrange(len(lines))
lines[choice_idx] = lines[choice_idx].upper()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for being unclear with my question.